# Two text in button, title and subtitle

Tags: android, button

Can we create some custom button with title and subtitle text in it.

Title in upper part of button and subtitle below it.

Comment: why are you not using image ??

Comment: As text in title and subtitle changes often

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You do not need any images the thing you need is styled text
and here is simple and short way to do it

```
button1.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b><big>" + "Title" + "</big></b>" +  "<br />" + 
        "<small>" + "subtitle" + "</small>" + "<br />"));
```

You do not need to change any layout just add this text to your button

Comment: that did a trick for me, thanks for answer, could have given +20 if allowed to :)

Comment: :), you are welcomed . . ., I god the same felling like you when I found this thing for the first time :)

Comment: Just a note: `<small><small>text</small></small>` makes the text even smaller

Comment: doesn't work w/ material design buttons any more FYI

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this problem logically the logic is that.

```
android:text="Titel \n subTitle"
```

Comment: Zoombie wants that the text in the Button is change dynamically . so this solution is not possible i think.

Comment: @sujit i think i should try with two adjacent button